# ExtJs - custom class resolution

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

Let's say I have a concrete view named "view." I would like, at runtime, be able to call `Ext.create("view_1")` or `Ext.create({ xtype: "view_5" })` and they will create instances of "view".

So any xtype matching the regex: /view_[0-9]+/ should create a "view" instead.

Is this possible, if so how?

More details,

We added the ability for our users to create custom reports. They define the menu name, the title, the set of columns, and the data constraint to be used. Each custom report is constructed using the same xtype `view`.

The problem arise when we save the state for these custom reports. Normally, we use the xtype as key for storage. So if all custom reports are the same xtype they override each other's state.

The direct workaround is to have different xtype for each custom report. So `"view_1", "view_5", "view_1008"...view_[0-9]+` are the xtypes associated with `custom report #1, custom report #5, custom report #1008...custom report [0-9]+`. But they all should be constructed using xtype `view`.

If we create aliases, we would need to add all reasonable/possible form of `view_[0-9]+`. I am not sure this approach scales very well when we have more types of dynamic views.

Comment: What's the point in having an `xtype` for each of them? This defeats the whole idea.

Comment: 2 views are the same if they have the same xtype. If I want each custom report to be treated as different views, they need their own xtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't possible to create a view from regex.
In my opinion, the best way you can do is to set alias as list of strings.
Example:

```
Ext.define('SomeView', {
    alias: ['widget.view_1', 'widget.view_2', 'widget.view_3', 'widget.view_4' ...],
});
```

Update ( according to the comment ) : 
Maybe you want to create multiple views (same definition) with id like:

```
Ext.create("SomeView", {
    id: "view_1",
});
Ext.create("SomeView", {
    id: "view_2",
});
```

**Update :**

The other way is to override `Ext.create` function.

Example on https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32lj

```
Ext.apply(Ext, {
    _create: Ext.create
});

Ext.override(Ext, {
    create: function () {
        var name = arguments[0],
        nameType = typeof name;

        if(nameType == 'string'){
            let regex = /widget\.viewx_[0-9]+/;
            let found = name.match(regex);

            if (found) {
                name = "widget.viewx";
            }
        }

        return Ext._create(name, arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3]);
    }
});
```

And usage:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'viewx',
                fieldLabel: "AA"
            }, {
                xtype: 'viewx_1',
                fieldLabel: "AA"
            }, {
                xtype: 'viewx_2',
                fieldLabel: "AA"
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: the suffix are the ids from the database, so they are not known until runtime. It is possible to just specify a range of "valid" alias but that would require declaring thousands of aliases.

Comment: Check my update, maybe this is what are you looking for. Here aren't other solution.

Comment: provided more details about the scenario I am facing, hopefully it makes things clearer.

Comment: Can't you save state per created view identifier instead of xtype?

Comment: things has been built this way; it is certainly possible to re-work the state management for these displays but I would like to avoid that. My hope is that there is a built-in (extensible) feature to support this.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I just changed the function `Ext.create`.

Comment: This aligns more with what I have in mind. Thank you much.